# Flutter and Dart Plugins Android Studios

Tags: dart, flutter

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ ANDROID_HOME = User/grantrienstra/Library/Android/sdk
      but Android SDK not found at this location.

Is what I've been getting when I run flutter doctor -v and Youtube has not yielded any answers. Do you know how to install the Android toolchain?  I have Android Studios downloaded and the Flutter and Dart plugins integrated.

Comment: This? - https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools

Answer (score 1):

By checking your path I'm assuming you're on Mac so try to add the `tools` and `platform-tools` to your `PATH` environment variable by running the following on the terminal:

> export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/tools
>
> export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

Then you should be good to go.